# Laravel Guru: Is it possible to use newly added columns in Eloquent query?

Tags: php, laravel

The following is a MySQL query. I know it is wrong because the EXTRA column cannot be used in the query.

```sql
SELECT users.id, user_time.*, CONCAT(users.info1, users.info2) AS EXTRA FROM users JOIN user_time ON users.id = user_time.user_id WHERE EXTRA ="ABCDEFG";
```

But isn't it possible to use this EXTRA column in Laravel?
Something like...

```php
$table = User::join('user_time','user_time.user_id','users.id')->select('users.id','user_time.*',DB::raw("CONCAT(users.info1, users.info2) AS EXTRA"));
$table = $table->where('EXTRA','=','ABCDEFG');
```

I am not sure what data is saved in variable $table.
If there is a method similar to the above, it would save me a lot of code writing.

Comment: did you try that?

Answer (score 1):

From what you are trying to attempt above, it seems can be done easily with eloquent.

Apparently UserTime belongsTo User and User has many UserTime

```php
class User extends Model
{
    public function user_times()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(UserTime::class();
    }
 
    //...rest of class code
}


class UserTime extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    //... rest of class code
}
```

Say you are trying to match that `CONCAT(users.info1, users.info2) = 'somevalue'` then you can try the following to get the desired output.

```php
$data = User::with('user_times')
    ->where([
        ['info1', 'some'],
        ['info2', 'value']
    ])
    ->get();
```

OR using raw expressions

```php
$data = User::with('user_times')
    ->whereRaw('CONCAT(users.info1,users.info2) = "somevalue"')
    ->selectRaw('id, CONCAT(users.info1,users.info2) AS Extra')
    ->get();
```

Comment: I must make clear that "Users" and "User_time" are distinct tables with Users.id as a foreign key.  But what is the purpose of function user_times() in Model User?

Comment: `user_times()` in the User model is a function which defines the relationship between User model (records) and UserTime model (records). Eloquent has very powerful mechanism via relationships between models to structure meaningful queries and get structured output with an elegant syntax. Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: *"Users" and "User_time" are distinct tables* : Yes of course **users** & **user_times** are two different tables represented by **User** and **UserTime** model respectively